# HashSet no serialized java spring roo

Tags: java, json, serialization, set, spring-roo

I've java class like that:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooJson

public class class1 {

    /**
     */
    @ManyToOne
    private type1 value1;

    /**
     */
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "xxxxxx")
    private Set<type2> value2 = new HashSet<type2>();
}
```

So, when I try to view values of this class with `toJson()` (auto-generated by Roo) just `value1` are serialized and no my `Set<type2>`

If I want to serialize value2 too, I must type :

```
instanceClass1.toJson(new String[]{"value2"});
```

How to do for the default method `toJson()` serialize the `Set<type2>` too?

Thanks

I found a kind of solution

```
 public String StringSims.toJson() {
    return new JSONSerializer().include(new String[]{"value2"}).exclude("*.class").serialize(this);
 }
```

I'm not sure it's not the best solution :) I'm waiting for you suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Your "kind of solution" is solution for real, you can filter fields what JSONSerializer should return (methods include() and exclude()) - default behavior is not to return cascading relations. In your case use include for every "value2":

```
public String StringSims.toJson() {
    return new JSONSerializer().
            include("*.value2").
            exclude("*.class").
            exclude("*.version").
            serialize(this);
}
```